# Binary Search Tree recursive error and trace of operations

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

My job is to show the steps of inserting a randomly generated key (0-14012891) e.g. inserting to the left when a value is smaller and to the right when a value is greater. This is all I have so far and I am quite stuck, any kind of help/pointers would be greatly appreciated, also I have another error where my root 14012891 keeps being printed in a recursive manner after each new randomly generated number is added, how do I also get rid of this? Thank you!

```
Node root;

public void addNode(int key, String name) {

Node newNode = new Node(key, name);
if(root == null) {
    root = newNode;
} else {
    Node focusNode = root;
    Node parent;
    while(true) {
        parent = focusNode;
        if(key < focusNode.key) {
            focusNode = focusNode.leftChild;
            if(focusNode == null) {
                parent.leftChild = newNode;
                return;
            }
            else {
                focusNode = focusNode.rightChild;
                if (focusNode == null) {
                    parent.rightChild = newNode;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
public void preOrderTraverseTree(Node focusNode) {
    if (focusNode!=null) {
        System.out.println(focusNode);

        preOrderTraverseTree(focusNode.leftChild);

        preOrderTraverseTree(focusNode.rightChild);
    }
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    Random rand = new Random(); 
for (int j = 0; j<10; j++) 
{
int pick = rand.nextInt(100);

    CourseWork2 newTree = new CourseWork2();
    newTree.addNode(14012891," Root ");
    newTree.addNode(pick, "");

    newTree.preOrderTraverseTree(newTree.root);
}
}

public class Node {
int key;
String name;

Node leftChild;
Node rightChild;

Node(int key, String name) {

    this.key = key;

    this.name = name;

}
public String toString () {
    return name + " " + key;
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, first of all you are creating a new tree each iteration through the for loop that you have so it will have no nodes. and then you are adding a root node and a random number from 0-100. Therefore the expected result from this is that it will print out the root node and the random number 10 times. In other words your tree never grows bigger than 2 nodes.

Secondly, your add method isnt recursive. you are setting the root to be the max value in your range, so the first iteration through the while loop will always end in a termination (return) therefore the add can never traverse down below the second level of your tree.

Hope this helps you get in the right direction.